# Pass data (retrieved from server) from parent route to its child route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My Angular application have parent and child route. I am using (ui-router)
I what to build that parent route data (which are retrieved from server using $resource) are passed to its child route.

Here will be my application code. When I debugged my code, then "phaseTasks" in child route always was empty Array.

```
flowAdminApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider
      .state('phase', {
        url: "/phases/:phase_id",
        template: JST['layouts/admin/flows/tasks/index'],
        resolve: {
          phaseTasks: ['$stateParams', 'taskData',
            function( $stateParams, taskData ){
              return taskData.getPhaseTasks($stateParams.phase_id);
          }]
        },
        controller: 'taskListController'
      })
      .state('phase.task', {
        url: "/tasks/:task_id",
        template: JST['layouts/admin/flows/tasks/show'],
        resolve: {
          task: ['$stateParams', 'phaseTasks',
            function( $stateParams, phaseTasks ){

              // phaseTasks is empty Array

          }]
        },
        controller: 'taskController'
      })
}]);

flowAdminApp.factory('taskData', [ '$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return {
      getPhaseTasks: function (phase_id) {
        return $resource('/admin/tasks.json?phase_id=:phase_id', {phase_id:'@phase_id'}).query({phase_id:phase_id});
      }
    }
}]);
```

#### When I changed my code that parent data are static, then "phaseTasks" passed to child route correctly.

```
flowAdminApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$stateProvider
  .state('phase', {
    url: "/phases/:phase_id",
    template: JST['layouts/admin/flows/tasks/index'],
    resolve: {
      phaseTasks: ['$stateParams',
        function( $stateParams ){
          return [{a: 1}]
      }]
    },
    controller: 'taskListController'
  })
  .state('phase.task', {
    url: "/tasks/:task_id",
    template: JST['layouts/admin/flows/tasks/show'],
    resolve: {
      task: ['$stateParams', 'phaseTasks',
        function( $stateParams, phaseTasks ){

          // phaseTasks is [{a: 1}] 


      }]
    },
    controller: 'taskController'
  })
}]);
```

How to pass data (retrieved from server) from parent route to its child route or prevent child route loading until parent route data are retrieved from database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement your `getPhaseTasks` service method using a promise

```
flowAdminApp.factory('taskData', [ '$resource','$q'
  function ($resource,$q) {
    return {
      getPhaseTasks: function (phase_id) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $resource('/admin/tasks.json?phase_id=:phase_id', {phase_id:'@phase_id'})
         .query({phase_id:phase_id},
            function(data){
                defer.resolve(data);
             },
            function(error) {
                defer.reject(error);
            });
        return defer.promise;
      }
    }
}]);
```

I think the problem currently is that the `$resource` api is async in nature and returns an array, which gets filled in the future. Since there is no promise available for your `$state` routes the resolve function does not wait.